# Calling an executable by a different name

Tags: windows

I installed QT for windows, and it uses mingw. There it has this mingw32-make, but I would like to be able to just call make whenever I want to use it.. as it is rather long to type that. Anyone know how to do this?

I know I can make a copy of mingw32-make, and rename it make in order to get something to work, but that is just so lame. Is there a more elegant way.

Ted.

Comment: this belongs to superuser, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a batch file that is in your "PATH" that calls the mingw32-make file for you.

Answer (score 4):

Create a batch file on your PATH (I put mine in `c:\MinGW\bin`) called `make.bat` with the following contents:

```
mingw32-make %*
```

The `%*` enables you to pass arguments to the mingw32-make command.

Thanks to a2j for pointing me in the right direction here.

Comment: It's funny, my answer is over a year and a half old. Seeing it again now I feel like I could write it so much better. It is good to see how we improve over time...:)

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows command prompt ( `C:\xxx\>` ),
use the good old [`doskey`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSKey) tricks. Add this to your `msys.bat` / `cygwin.bat` (or type it manually)

```
DOSKEY make=mingw32-make $*
```

and you can use `make` instead of `mingw32-make`.

If you use the bash shell (`admin@computer ~$`), edit `~/.bashrc`, add this line:

```
alias make=mingw32-make
```

Comment: Hmm I actually need the mingw from windows to do this. I am only using Qt's version of mingw. Does Cygwin have something similar to msys.bat