# "doskey" Scons building error

Tags: build, node.js, mingw, scons, mingw-w64

I'm trying to (cross-)compile node.js and I get this odd error that appears to be coming from scons:

```
$ make
Waf: Entering directory `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\Adam\Stuff\node\build'
[51/71] libv8.a: deps\v8\SConstruct -> build\default\libv8.a
'"c:\Program Files\Python27\python.exe" "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\Adam\Stuff\node\tools/scons/scons.py" -j 1 -C "C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/Adam/Stuff/node/build/default/" -Y "C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/Adam/Stuff/node/deps/v8" visibility=default mode=release arch=x64 toolchain=gcc library=static '
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o obj\release\accessors.o -c -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wnon-virtual-dtor -pedantic -Wno-long-long -m64 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -DWIN32 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -DWIN32 -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wnon-virtual-dtor -pedantic -Wno-long-long -m64 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -DWIN32 -fno-strict-aliasing -DV8_TARGET_ARCH_X64 -DENABLE_VMSTATE_TRACKING -DENABLE_LOGGING_AND_PROFILING -DENABLE_DEBUGGER_SUPPORT -IC:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\Adam\Stuff\node\deps\v8\src C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\Adam\Stuff\node\deps\v8\src\accessors.cc
scons: building terminated because of errors.

'doskey' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'doskey' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
scons: *** [obj\release\accessors.o] Error 1

Waf: Leaving directory `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\Adam\Stuff\node\build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #2):
        {task: libv8.a SConstruct -> libv8.a}
DEST_OS: win32
DEST_CPU: x64
Parallel Jobs: 1
Product type: program
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

My build environment was a Windows 7, using mingw/msys and mingw-w64 tools. I can't even find any reference to doskey in any of the scripts that seem to be running so I'm quite stuck.

Thanks

Comment: Did you (dumb question I know) make sure doskey was available to that build environment? Try CDing to that path and making sure it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question should describe why it is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120840/calling-an-executable-by-a-different-name). However, `doskey` is available on my Windows 7 Pro machine so I don't understand why it is not working for you. I'm sure you could pull it off a WinXP machine if you have one available.

If you can find the file, you could always drop it somewhere in your `%PATH%` and see if it makes a difference?

Alternatively, put a copy of the file in the directory that the build script is being run in.

Comment: doskey is actually present and working on the system, which introduces another oddity.

Comment: That is odd. Can you post the makefile?

Comment: Makefile: http://pastebin.com/w26TCy7w The problem is that there's many different build systems in play, make calls waf, and for building v8, waf calls scons. The wscript that waf uses is at https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/wscript

Comment: Hmm. I've read through them both and can't make sense of it. There is a nodejs IRC channel on freenode, might be worth asking those guys. Sorry I couldn't help!

Comment: Wow, that was silly of me... I never actually tried to copy doskey.exe into node/build/default . i have no idea why it needed it but it worked so thanks..