# How can I make CMake use Mingw-w64 gcc/g++?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, g++, mingw-w64

I am on Windwos trying to get Mingw-w64 to work with CMake since my MSVC is somehow not working at all (using Windows10 64bit.

Basically I add the arguments `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"` to my call to CMake which sets the corresponding compiler.

However I get these errors:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.
```

How could I get this to work?

Comment: Can you launch *"C:/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"* (e.g. from *cmd*)? You might also want to try the *Win* path style: *"C:\MinGW-w64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe"* (if that doesn't work either you could tye doubling the "**\\**"s)

Comment: Also you want to add *C:\MinGW-w64\mingw64\bin* in *%PATH%*.

Answer (score 38):

The simplest way to generate makefiles for MinGW (and MinGW-w64) is to use the appropriate CMake generator. Just call cmake with

```
-G "MinGW Makefiles"
```

no need to set DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER and DCMAKE_C_COMPILER by hand.

For this to work, CMake must find your compilers. So this path must be added to the windows PATH variable, as CristiFati pointed out:

```
C:/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin
```

To check if the PATH is correct, fire up a Windows command prompt and run

```
where gcc
```

The output should be (at least) the path you just added to the Windows PATH variable.

Comment: You hadditionally have to specify CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM to mingw32-make

Comment: we specifically want to use mingw64, isn't that contradictory to set the make programe to mingw32? am I missing something?

Comment: @Patafikss somewhat confusingly, mingw64 is invoked by calling mingw32. mingw32 is used to compile both 32-bit and 64-bit binaries.

Comment: @sancelot you can make a batch program called make.bat that refer to mingw32-make.exe.  Place this batch program in the MinGW bin folder.  See [Calling an executable by a different name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120840/calling-an-executable-by-a-different-name/11349488#11349488)